# List of named ChartLayout themes

Tags: charts

The documentation page for [ChartLayout](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartLayout.html) shows a few examples for themes such as "Grouped" and "Stacked".

How can a list of the available `ChartLayout` themes be retrieved?

Thanks for your help.